# how to get current uilabel text from uiscroll view runtime

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have task to develop the application with words counting and display in runtime generated uiscrollview with uilabel as subview.

The process is like when user will load page at that time the 1000 of word will fill in the rutime generated uilabel with scrollview.And all thing is set from runtime. but it the application we have one button to add the current uilabel text on button click.

and the words are coming random from database. when i click on the button it gives me the different word. from scroll view displayed word.

Following is my code to fill the data in uilabel with scrollview :

```
wordName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 2)];
                [wordNameArray addObject:wordName];
int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
    {
        randomN = [wordNameArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [wordNameArray count]];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"word_bg.png"];
        word = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,12,250,120)];
        [word setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:36.0f]];
        word.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        word.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        word.numberOfLines = 2;
        word.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        word.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [word setText:randomN];
        lblWord.text = word.text;

        word.tag = i;
        NSLog(@"tag no:%d",word.tag);

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imageView addSubview:word];

        CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
        rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
        rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.tag = i;  

        //NSLog(@"%@",word.text);
        //NSLog(@"%@",lblWord.text);

        //  [scrollView1 addSubview:l];
        [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];

        touchToSee.hidden = TRUE;
        [imageView release];
    }

    [self layoutScrollImages];
```

Following is my scroll event to get the word from label but it is giving me last word from array:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    touchToSee.hidden = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"word-%@",word.text);

}
```

And other when i click on button i am not getting the perfect work so for that following is my code:

```
NSString *getword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",word.text];
    NSLog(@"lblCountdownBackward:%@",word.text);
```

So please help me and provide me some sample code for it if it possible.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be creating lots of word objects, and adding them to the screen.

In your for loop, you perform your code upto `kNumImages`. And in each run, the `word` Object is replace with a new one.

So when you get the word later on, it will be the very last `word` object you created (hence the last word).

To get arround this you could use an `NSMutableArray` and keep adding a new `UILabel` object to that (instead of creating the `word` object). And then later on do something like

```
[array objectAtIndex:0].text;
```